# Automapper source prefix property

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-5

We are designing a temporal system where the definition of an entity can change. I am trying to setup Automapper but can't quite work out how the prefix should work.

As an example, I would have the following entity:

```
public class ReferenceDataDefinition
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ReferenceData 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ReferenceDataDefinition Current { get; set; }
}
```

With the following DTO:

```
public class ReferenceDataDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I know I can use

```
CreateMap<ReferenceData, ReferenceDataDTO>()
    .ForMember(p => p.Id, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Id)
    .ForMember(p => p.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Current.Name);
```

But I feel there must be something smarter I can do?
I've tried adding RecognizePrefixes("Current") but that had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried adding RecognizePrefixes("Current")

This isn't how prefix are used. They are for a scenario where your properties start with a prefix (often because of a database naming schema).

For example, If you had the following classes:

```
public class ReferenceData 
{
    public int Ref_Id { get; set; }
    public string Ref_Name { get; set; }
}

public class ReferenceDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You could recognize the following prefix:

```
cfg.RecognizePrefixes("Ref_");
```

AutoMapper would then be able to map those two objects without you having to define specific mappings with `.ForMember`.

Regarding you own mapping, since both `Id` properties on `ReferenceData` and `ReferenceDataDTO` have the same name, you should be able to remove the Id member mapping as AutoMapper can infer it automatically:

```
CreateMap<ReferenceData, ReferenceDataDTO>()
    .ForMember(p => p.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Current.Name);
```

This should suffice.

As for `.Current` using [Flattening](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening) you could remove it if you would change your DTO class to rename it to `CurrentName`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this documentation: 
[Recognizing pre/postfixes](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#recognizing-prepostfixes)
Also the RecognizePrefixes works for source object prefixes
Use RecognizeDestinationPrefixes method

Check these previous posts:
[AutoMapper with prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321487/automapper-with-prefix)
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/421